# How do I get a newline in the PHP output from echo?

Tags: php

I am generating a large amount of HTML code with PHP using `echo` and it is all appearing on one line.

I understand that HTML ignores whitespace, and there are thousands of answers which point out that you need `<BR>` or a block element. But that is not my question.

My problem is that is very hard to debug my HTML *source code* when it is all on one line. I am using Windows 7 and the Firefox browser tool **Page Source** to show the *source code*.

For a simple example, if the text editor I use shows

```
<HTML><BODY>
Hello, World!
</BODY></HTML>
```

Then the browser source code tool shows exactly that too, and when I generate it with PHP like

```
<?php
echo "<HTML><BODY>";
echo "Hello, World!";
echo "</BODY></HTML>";
?>
```

then the browser tool shows, as you would expect,

```
<HTML><BODY>Hello, World!</BODY></HTML>
```

I want to break the lines, and have tried

```
<?php
echo "<HTML><BODY>\n";
echo "Hello, World!\n";
echo "</BODY></HTML>\n";
?>
```

and with `"\r\n"` and with `"\xA"` and also like this

```
<?php
echo "<HTML><BODY>" . PHP_EOL;
echo "Hello, World!" . PHP_EOL;
echo "</BODY></HTML>" . PHP_EOL;
?>
```

yet the content stays resolutely on a single line.

Comment: Instead of just "\n" to use "\r\n"

Comment: Make sure you don't have webserver modules which clear spaces/linebreaks.

Comment: @u_mulder the source code from my text editor which I know includes newlines is showing them correctly. And the server sends a normal HTML file including any line breaks.

Comment: What are you looking at the html using?

Comment: Is it possible that the PHP server module removes any I put in?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am using Firefox option: Tools - Browser tools - page source.

Comment: @WeatherVane Is the page publicly available for checking/testing?

Comment: What is your expected output? Have you tried other browsers?

Comment: Why not use the element inspector in the developer tools? It will show you formatted html and you can do so much more with it too

Comment: @FaridVatani In my test environment the PHP server is local: QuickPHP by Zach Saw. Thanks for the reminder, it's a much longer edit/upload/clearcache developement cycle on the target webserver.

Comment: @ADyson thanks, I do and I notice that it gets reformatted. The most bugs derive from unmatched tag and quote pairs which are easier to find if I copy paste the browser's source code into a markup text editor.

Comment: Instead of echoing the HTML through PHP, wouldn't it be easier to just close the PHP block `?>`, write the HTML you want and then open it again `<?php` if you need more PHP after? That would also give you the benefit of most IDE's syntax highlighting the HTML when editing the file.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson that is a good idea. I have just tried that out, going in and out of php generation, but the same thing happens: No line breaks.

Comment: Does it happen if you don't have any PHP code at all in the file (which should give you the same result, tbh)? If that's the case, then it's a web server issue, not a PHP issue.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thanks I've now looked at the output from the real webserver, which does contain line breaks. So it's the local QuickPHP server which must be removing them. It doesn't have an option related to that. I thought it was my poor understanding of PHP to be at fault.

Comment: Have you tried using PHP's built in web server while working locally? Or XAMPP (if you need database etc)

Answer (score 1):

This works on windows

```
<?php
echo "<HTML><BODY>
";
echo "Hello, World!
";
echo "</BODY></HTML>
";
?>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just have one echo and have the new lines in the string?

Comment: That wouldn't work in the browser console or view source...if your were to save the file you'd do that..

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have just tried this but the source code still lacks any line breaks.

Comment: Like you clicked on view page source? this is working on any browser on mine doesn't make sense it does not work on yours anyone can confirm this?

Comment: What version of firefox are you using? would you attach a screenshot

Comment: I have determined it is the PHP server, not my coding or the browser. I posted the output text in the question.